# Firestore get subcollection parent document ID - JavaScript

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following structure in my Firestore DB: several `UserLists` collections, which hold the `Users`. Each user may have a `Notes` subcollection.

I'm doing a subcollection group query that works well, returning notes from across the Notes subcollection.

**My question is, from the Note document retrieved from the Notes subcollection, can I get the parent document ID? That would be User 1 in the below example. Using JavaScript.**

```
Collection: UserList 1
  Doc: User 1
    Subcollection: Notes
      Doc: Note 1

Collection: UserList 2
  Doc: User 1
    Subcollection: Notes
      Doc: Note 1
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use one of the following approaches:

```
  const query = ......;
  query
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.ref.path);
        console.log(doc.ref.parent.parent.id);
      });
    })
```

---

On each `QueryDocumentSnapshot`, you can use the [`ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot#ref) property, which returns a `DocumentReference`. Then, on this `DocumentReference` you use the [`path`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#path) property, which will return the full path, e.g. `UserList1/User1/Notes/Doc1`.

Or you use the [`parent`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#parent) property of the `DocumentReference`, which returns a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference), then you use again the [`parent`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#parent) property (of the `CollectionReference` this time) to get the parent `DocumentReference` and then the `id` property of this parent `DocumentReference`.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm not sure how I missed this in the docs. Exactly what I was looking for!