# How to get Firebase array of documents ids from colletion where documents have No Data but only sub collections?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, collections

I don't know if this is a bug with Firebase, or maybe it's stated in their documentation, I can't get the IDs from the collection where the document has No fields but Only Subcollection. Please assist me with this. I tried to put some field on some document, then it has shown, then I deleted it again still it shows and I confirmed it's not Cache by opening Incognito on Chrome and still the document was only one showing even though I deleted the field I was testing with. My collection structure looks as on the image attached What I am trying to get is the Ids inside invoices. My current code is I am using Javascript:-

```
async getMarker() {
        const snapshot = await this.db.collection("customer_invoices").get()
        return snapshot.docs.map((doc: any) => doc.id);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to query those parent documents, as they don't exist. The console only shows these placeholders so that you can navigate to the subcollections.

The only way I can think of to get these IDs is to do [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) on all your `invoices` subcollections, and then [find the parent document of each invoice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61011280/firestore-get-subcollection-parent-document-id-javascript).

Also see:

- [Get parents from Firestore Collection Group Query, WITHOUT RETRIEVING SONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62987772/get-parents-from-firestore-collection-group-query-without-retrieving-sons)